# Какой смысл в каналах изображения?

Tags: python, изображения, matplotlib

Есть изображения с размером

```
(1280, 1918, 3)
```

и маска к нему с размером

```
(1280, 1918, 1)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=5, figsize=(25, 25))
axes[0].imshow(img)
axes[1].imshow(img[...,0])
axes[2].imshow(img[...,1])
axes[3].imshow(img[...,2])
axes[4].imshow(mask[...,0])
plt.show()
```

Как видно из изображения каналы не имеют различия, какой в них смысл?

иди другой пример

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=4, figsize=(34, 34))
axes[0].imshow(m)
axes[1].imshow(m[...,0])
axes[2].imshow(m[...,1])
axes[3].imshow(m[...,2])
plt.show()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Насчет вашего второго вопроса: `И можно ли отобразить на графике отдельный пиксель?` - стоит задать отдельный вопрос, а не задавать 10 вопросов в одном :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы ушли в крайности - ч/б изображения.

**RGBA** - это аббревиатура:

- **R**ed
- **G**reen
- **B**lue
- **A**lpha

RGB в вашем случае и RGBA отличаются лишь наличием альфа-канала, который отвечает за прозрачность и, по сути, никакого отношения к цвету конкретного пикселя не имеет, если не затрагивать всякие смешивания цветов - это уже совсем другая история.

И, на самом то деле, каналы цветных изображений не одинаковы:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Значения каждого пикселя во всех каналах - число от 0 до 255 или же иногда его исчисляют в диапазоне от 0 до 1. Это разные представления одного и того же значения (перевод между этими представлениями - либо делим на 255, либо умножаем на 255). Где 0 - это черный цвет, а 1 или 255 - белый цвет.

Отдельным случаем являются ч/б изображения, вся магия в них заключается в том, что для каждого отдельного пикселя значения во всех 3х цветовых каналах одинаковые.

Можно также взглянуть на формулу перевода цветного изображения в ч/б эквивалент:

```
Y = 0.2125 R + 0.7154 G + 0.0721 B
```

Каждый пиксель в ч/б изображении - это сумма цветов (числа от 0 до 1 или от 0 до 255) из 3х каналов, помноженные на специальные коэффициенты. Что за коэффициенты и почему они такие к вопросу не относится, но если вкратце: это связано с "неоднородным" восприятием цветов глазом человека.

---

Данная концепция аналогична и для второго примера - там тоже ч/б изображение.